# dynamic_cast to derived type with unknown template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to `dynamic_cast` to a templated derived type, with unknown template argument:

```
struct A {
    virtual void f() { };
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct B : public A { };
```

With the known template argument the cast can be performed as:

```
const A& base_ref = B<N>();
const B<N>& ref = dynamic_cast<const B<N>&>(base_ref);
```

My question is about the case where the value of the template argument (`N`) is not known.

I was wondering if there is a way to obtain the object type, in this case `B<N>` from the base class pointer/reference, such that the dynamic_cast template parameter can be inferred automatically?

P.S. In the considered case the template argument is an integer type, and is used as a template parameter for an `std::array`.

Comment: what kind of object would hold a reference to the unknown result of the cast? The only option would be something known like the base class, making the dynamic cast obsolete. 
To be honest this use case smells bad. Polymorphic relationships assert that B<N> *is a kind of* A, and that useful methods will be on A's interface, not B's

Comment: You are right. This was kind of a forced attempt. I was just hoping there would be a straightforward solution to get the templated type of the object pointed by the base reference directly. In the particular case the derived types differ only in the size of a member std::array, therefore having a highly constrained setup.

Comment: Can you modify the base class to expose polymorphic begin/end or data/size members?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just a few possible values of `N`, then you can try `dynamic_cast`'ing to each of them. Otherwise, the answer is:

No. As a compile time constant, no. If you don't need a compile time constant, then you can do this:

```
struct AWithN {
  int n;

  AWithN(int n_) : n(n_) { }
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct B: public AWithN {
  B() : AWithN(N) { }
};
```

And you can `dynamic_cast` to AWithN, from where you can get `n`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is going to be nasty.

You can automate the lookup of a valid dynamic cast, **if**:

1. You cap the maximum value of `N` in `B<N>` to a value your compiler will be happy with.
2. You provide a visitor taking a template argument in order to action the result of a successful cast.
3. You don't mind sequential lookups (although further work here[1] would involve building a cache of successful lookups to improve runtime).

[1] further work would obviously be a waste of time. The time would be better spent working on a better design.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

struct A
{
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

template<std::size_t N>
struct B : A
{

};

template<std::size_t I>
struct cast_test
{
    static bool test(A* p) {
        return dynamic_cast<B<I>*>(p) != nullptr;
    }
};

template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto make_cast_tests(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<bool(*)(A*), sizeof...(Is)> {
        &cast_test<Is>::test...
    };
}

template<class Visitor, std::size_t I>
struct caller
{
    // figuring out a common return type is a whole new challenge...
    static void call(Visitor& visitor, A* p) {
        return visitor(static_cast<B<I>*>(p));
    }
};

template<class Visitor, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto make_callers(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::array<void(*)(Visitor&, A*), sizeof...(Is)> {
        &caller<Visitor, Is>::call...
    };
}

template<std::size_t N, class Visitor, class sequence_type = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
decltype(auto) dynamic_visit(Visitor&& visitor, A*p)
{
    constexpr auto tests = make_cast_tests(sequence_type());
    auto ipos = std::find_if(std::begin(tests), std::end(tests), [&p](auto&& f){ return f(p); });
    if (ipos == std::end(tests))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("increase the range of N");
    }

    constexpr auto callers = make_callers<Visitor>(sequence_type());
    auto icaller = std::begin(callers) + std::distance(std::begin(tests), ipos);
    return (*icaller)(visitor, p);
}

struct visitor
{
    template<std::size_t I>
    void operator()(B<I>* p) const
    {
        std::cout << "I is " << I << std::endl;
    }

};

auto make_an_A(int argc) -> A*
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        return new B<6>;
    }
    else {
        return new B<7>;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* p = make_an_A(argc);
    dynamic_visit<100>(visitor(), p);
}
```

expected result when invoked with ./a.out:

```
I is 7
```

expected result when invoked with ./a.out "foo":

```
I is 6
```